# gnuplot how to zoom y & y2 axis

Tags: zooming, gnuplot

I have a plot like this using wgnuplot:

the green and blue are on y2 axis.

[image]

Question 1:

When I zoom using right mouse button I get:

[image]

The black line on yaxis is to compressed near top. How can I get the y scale to fit the data for this window at this point AUTOMATICALLY. I.e.e without me having to type range commands?

Questions 2:

Again, is there anyway to rescale/zoom the y2axis ALONE, by mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press 'a' or click the `autoscale` button to adjust the y-scale. Maybe you want to use `set autoscale xfix` before that.

Its not by mouse, but you can use the `bind` command to rescale only the `y2`-axis with the hotkeys 'alt-z' and 'alt-y':

```
bind 'alt-z' 'set y2range[GPVAL_Y2_MIN*2:GPVAL_Y2_MAX*2]; replot'
bind 'alt-y' 'set y2range[GPVAL_Y2_MIN*0.5:GPVAL_Y2_MAX*0.5]; replot'
```

Comment: Great. The bind works perfectly - thank you very much.  However, pressing 'a' when I am in a zoomed window - removes all zooming - I want to keep the xAxis range that I zoomed to, and just refit Y and Y2

Comment: With version 4.6.4 on Linux, the following example works fine: `set ytics nomirror; set y2tics; set autoscale xfix; plot x, x**2`, zoom the x-axis with `ctrl+shift+<wheel-up>` several times an then hit 'a'. This adjusts only the y and y2-range.

Comment: Do you know a way to set a keybind to plot a vertical line at a specific date on mt xaxis?