# Zoom z axis on gnuplot 3d splot?

Tags: zooming, mouse, gnuplot

Is there an interactive way to zoom the z axis using mouse or keys?

I can change x or y but not z.

```
wheel scroll changes y axis.

shift-wheel scroll change x axis.
```

But no combination I have tried affect the z.

EDIT 1

At Christoph's suggestion I added some binds. The ctrl- show up when I type "bind" but do nothing. the Tab- ones do not even show up  when I type "bind"

```
bind 'Ctrl-Down' 'set yrange[GPVAL_Y_MIN+(0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)):GPVAL_Y_MAX+(0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN))]; replot'
bind 'Ctrl-Up' 'set yrange[GPVAL_Y_MIN-(0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)):GPVAL_Y_MAX-(0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN))]; replot'
bind 'Ctrl-Left' 'set yrange[GPVAL_Y_MIN-(0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)):GPVAL_Y_MAX+(0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN))]; replot'
bind 'Ctrl-Right' 'set yrange[GPVAL_Y_MIN+(0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)):GPVAL_Y_MAX-(0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN))]; replot'


bind 'Tab-Left' 'set zrange[GPVAL_Z_MIN+(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN)):GPVAL_Z_MAX+(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN))]; replot'
bind 'Tab-Right' 'set zrange[GPVAL_Z_MIN-(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN)):GPVAL_Z_MAX-(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN))]; replot'
bind 'Tab-Up' 'set zrange[GPVAL_Z_MIN-(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN)):GPVAL_Z_MAX+(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN))]; replot'
bind 'Tab-Down' 'set zrange[GPVAL_Z_MIN+(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN)):GPVAL_Z_MAX-(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN))]; replot'
```

Comment: Pressing the third button (mouse wheel) I can scale the z-axis, but not zoom it. Maybe you can use `bind` to create hotkey which zooms in z-direction, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20424056/2604213

Comment: @Christoph I already do that for x and y and y2 (if it exists) but the hotkeys appear to be ignored when using splot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Tab` as compositing key for a binding. When I try one of your lines like

```
bind 'Tab-Left' 'set zrange[GPVAL_Z_MIN+(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN)):GPVAL_Z_MAX+(0.2*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN))]; replot'
```

I get the message `bind: cannot parse Tab-Left` (tested with 4.6.4).

Using e.g `Alt-Left` works fine:

```
change_z(left,right) = sprintf('set zrange[GPVAL_Z_MIN+(%f*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN)):GPVAL_Z_MAX+(%f*(GPVAL_Z_MAX-GPVAL_Z_MIN))]; replot', left, right)
bind 'Alt-Left' 'eval(change_z(0.2, 0.2))'
bind 'Alt-Right' 'eval(change_z(-0.2, -0.2))'
bind 'Alt-Up' 'eval(change_z(-0.2, 0.2))'
bind 'Alt-Down' 'eval(change_z(0.2,-0.2))'
```